# Why function becoming undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have express session, which initializing in route method:

```
router.post('/add', function (req, res) {
   if (!req.session.cart) {
      req.session.cart = cartController.initializeCart();
   }
   cartController.addToCart(req.body.productId, req.session.cart, function(error, result) {
      error ? res.send(error) : res.send(200);
   })
});
```

And I have cart model as function

```
function cart() {
  this.ids = [];
  this.addProduct = function (id) {
    ids.push(id);
   }
}
```

Initialize method:

```
  var cartModel = require("../models/cart"); //UPD
  initializeCart: function() {
      return new cartModel();   //UPD exception throw right after this operation
  },
```

Add cart method:

```
   addToCart: function(id, cart, callback) {
      cart.addProduct(id);
       .....
```

Session:

```
var expressSession = require('express-session');
app.use(expressSession({
  secret: "someSecret"
}));
```

But calling cart.addProduct() doesn't occurs, because addProduct() is undefined. Using prototype doesn't help me.

Screen:
http://prntscr.com/5rz61t

Comment: Hi, can you post the code as one piece?

Comment: What are you using for session storage?

Comment: I've updated post, you can see.

Comment: Post the complete error message. And check the type and content of `cart` var, is `cart` really a `cart` instance?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `cartModel` function in your code.

Try `return new cart();` instead of `return new cartModel();`

Comment: There is cartModel i ncontroller. Sorry, I have'nt written this

Answer (score 1):

If `cart` is saved in a session storage system that does not keep or restore types, `cart` will not be a cart instance any longer but just a simple object.

```
router.post('/add', function (req, res) {
   var cart;
   cart = cartController.initializeCart();
   if (req.session.cart) {
      cart.ids = req.session.cart.ids;
   } else {
      req.session.cart = cart;
   }
   cartController.addToCart(req.body.productId, cart, function(error, result) {
      error ? res.send(error) : res.send(200);
   })
});
```